# $m$, $T$, $f$ and initial phase determines amplitude $A$ of a SHM?

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, linear-systems

I was trying to calculate all the stuffs of simple harmonic motion knowing the mass, frequency and initial phase.

with $\omega$ and $m$ I can calculate $k$, $\omega^2m=k$, with $f$, I can calculate $T$, $f=\frac{1}{T}$.

If I know $\phi$ and $x(t)=Acos(\omega t+\phi)$, I should be able to calculate $A$, right?

If I set $m$, $f$ and initial phase, the SHM should not be totally defined? I still don't know how to calculate $A$.

Answer (score 0):

No, the mass, frequency (or spring constant), and initial phase aren't enough to uniquely specify simple harmonic motion. You also need the initial amplitude. E.g. I can start the mass-spring system with the same initial phase but from two different initial displacements, which would obviously result in a different $x(t)$ trajectory.

Comment: But, if I change the amplitude, without changing the mass, this don't change the frequency?

Comment: @EmanuelDias Not at all, the amplitude is completely independent of the frequency and mass, it just depends on the where the object is let go at $t = 0$ relative to its equilibrium position. Think of it this way, if you had a mass-spring system in an experiment, the frequency would just depend on the mass and spring constant, while you can vary the initial position of the mass however you want by stretching/compressing the spring to your desired location and then letting go.

Comment: What I'm thinking is: the mass and frequency determines $\omega$ and spring constant. If I pick bigger amplitudes, the velocity of the mass should be bigger in the equilibrium position, so frequency should change.

Comment: @EmanuelDias Sure, the velocity changes, but that's different from the frequency. The velocity is $v(t) =\dot{x}(t)= A \omega \sin(\omega t + \phi)$. It increases *because $A$ is increasing*, not the frequency.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. If A become larger, the velocity increases, with frequency being the same.  Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @EmanuelDias No worries!